# XMLdata.modify Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-dml

I'm usint MS SQL 
and in XML field need update like this.

```
 UPDATE Table
 SET 
    IF (XMLdata.exist('/ns:root/Field/text()') = 0)
       XMLdata.modify('
            insert text{"New value"} 
            into (/ns:root/Field)[1]
      ')
    ELSE
       XMLdata.modify('
            replace value of (/ns:root/Field/text())[1]
            with "Replaced value"
       '),
  WHERE condition
```

Sample of 2 XML Files

**Version 1**

```
<ns:root ....>
    <Field />
</ns:root>
```

**Version 2**

```
<ns:root ....>
    <Field>Value</Field>
</ns:root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns)
UPDATE Document
SET
    XMLdata.modify('
        insert text{"New value"} 
        into (/ns:root/Field)[1]
    ')
WHERE 
     (XMLData.exist('(/ns:root/Field/text())[1]')=0)
AND condition;
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns)
UPDATE Document
SET 
    XMLdata.modify('
    replace value of (/ns:root/Field/text())[1]
    with "Replaced value"
')
WHERE condition;
```